What does luck do in PokéRogue?
When entering a shop in PokéRogue, there's a stat in the top right that says "Luck: D". What does the luck stat do?


The higher your luck is the better the chance of an item in the shop being upgraded to a higher tier.
You get luck by having shiny Pokémon in your party that aren't fainted. There are 3 tiers of shinys and the rarer ones give more points luck. If you have 0 shinys then you'll have a D like in the screen shot which gives you a 3.12% chance to have an item upgraded. With 1 shiny Pokémon of the lowest tier you'd have 3.92% chance, with 3 shiny Pokémon of the lowest tier you'd have a 5.48% chance. If all 6 of your Pokémon are tier 3 shinys you'd have 14 shiny points and would have a 14.3% chance of having the items in the shop upgraded which would be a crazy boost.
Hopefully this helps!
Here's a link to the wiki so you can see the information yourself and find other info on the game!
